# Change password implementation in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to implement a change password feature in my nodejs application. My problem is the *else* of my if statement when I compare the old password from the hash password in the database. I want refer/return the **callback** just like when the password is matched and update the password in may database. So that I can check whether it succeed/failed in my controller.

```js
//route file
router.post("/change-password", auth.authenticationMiddleware(), auth.change);


//controller
module.exports.change = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.new === req.body.confirm){
          let user = {
                id : req.user.id,
                old : req.body.current,
                new : req.body.new
            };
        users.changePassword(user, (err, result)=> {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
        });
        res.redirect("/");
    }else{
        res.redirect("/change-password");
    }

};

//model
module.exports.changePassword = (user, callback) => {
    db.query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE id=?",[user.id], (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        bcrypt.compare(user.current, result[0].password, (err, match) => {
            if (match){
                bcrypt.hash(user.new, saltRounds, function (er, hash) {
                    db.query("UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE id=?", [hash, user.id], callback);
                });
            }else {
             //callback
            }
        });
    });

};
```

Comment: Unclear question. Please elaborate or make clear what you want to achieve

Comment: What i want to achieve is to create a callback if the password did not match.

Comment: You have already created one (commented callback) , just call it in else condition when pass did not match `callback(true,false)`

Comment: Not a clear question, what you want to achieve be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the errors up stream instead of throwing them. You can also craft your own `Error` for when the passwords do not match.

```
//model
module.exports.changePassword = (user, callback) => {
    db.query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE id=?",[user.id], (error, result) => {
        if (error) return callback(error); // pass to caller
        bcrypt.compare(user.current, result[0].password, (err, match) => {
            if (err) return callback(err); // pass this one too!
            if (match){
                bcrypt.hash(user.new, saltRounds, function (er, hash) {
                    if (er) return callback(er); // and this one!!
                    db.query("UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE id=?", [hash, user.id], callback);
                });
            }else {
              // that's not good, send an error to the caller
              var err = new Error('Password does not match');
              err.code = 'BAD_PASSWORD';
              callback(err);
            }
        });
    });

};
```

In the controller you can check for that error and pass any other errors to the next error handling route. You probably also want to wait for the callback to be invoked before redirecting the user.

```
//controller
module.exports.change = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.new === req.body.confirm){
          let user = {
                id : req.user.id,
                old : req.body.current,
                new : req.body.new
            };
        users.changePassword(user, (err, result)=> {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'BAD_PASSWORD') {
                    // do something
                } else {
                   next(err); // pass the error to the next handler
                }
            } else {
                res.redirect("/");
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect("/change-password");
    }

};
```